# Connected speech resources

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, speech, books, ipa

I am very interested in British pronunciation, so I am looking for resources about connected speech and IPA in general.

The ideal would be a book with the transcription of dialogues or just sentences, or also something related to connected speech rules.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is "connected speech"?

Comment: Check this out: https://www.eslbase.com/tefl-a-z/connected-speech

Comment: Try [this](https://www.londonschool.com/blog/phonetic-alphabet/)